# Join Date and time for events from sheet to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

With this code I can send the events directly to google calendar from google sheets. The start date and end date are on two different columns (col D and col F), the problem is that I need also the time that are on others two columns (col E and col G).
How could I join startDate with date+time and endDate with date+time?

```
function sendToCalendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('XCALENDAR')
  var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("O1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:P5").getValues(); 
  
  for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
  {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[3];
    var endTime = shift[5];
    var nameevent= shift[1];
    var desc= shift[13];
    var color = shift[15];
    var event = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime,{description:desc});

    if(color){
      event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample data for columns D, E, F and G showing the value (shown in the formula bar when the corresponding cell is selected ) and the display value (shown in the cell, might vary due to cell formatting)

Comment: hello, this is the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jo8TmUyb4zmGsAS4e1DJCsdHnCJlQGRUiYdKSVVvKR4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To concatenate date (d) and  time (t), you can do it this way

```
new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), t.getHours(), t.getMinutes(), t.getSeconds())
```

try with

```
function createEvent() { 
  // A = title, B = description, C = location, D = begin .. E = at, F = end ... G = at
  const myCalend = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  const [headers, ...data] = sh.getRange('A1:H' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  const colID = 8; // H
  data.forEach((r, index) => {
    if (r[colID - 1] == '') {
      let [title, desc, loc] = [r[0], r[1], r[2]]
      let [bd, bh, ed, eh] = [r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6]]
      let id = (myCalend.createEvent(
        title,
        new Date(bd.getFullYear(), bd.getMonth(), bd.getDate(), bh.getHours(), bh.getMinutes(), bh.getSeconds()),
        new Date(ed.getFullYear(), ed.getMonth(), ed.getDate(), eh.getHours(), eh.getMinutes(), eh.getSeconds()),
        {
          description: desc,
          location: loc
        }).getId())
      sh.getRange(index + 2, colID).setValue(id)
    }
  })
}
```

### edit

according to your spreadsheet, and assuming that dates are as dd/MM/yyyy, you can use (the eventID will be stored in column M=13 and prevent duplicating event)

```
function sendToCal() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Foglio1')
  let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:M" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var col = 13; // M
  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    if (shift[(col - 1)] == '') {
      let [d, e, f, g] = [shift[3].split("/"), shift[4].split(":"), shift[5].split("/"), shift[6].split(":")]
      let [nameevent, desc, color] = [shift[1], shift[11], shift[12]]
      var startTime = new Date(parseInt(d[2]), parseInt(d[1])-1, parseInt(d[0]), parseInt(e[0]), parseInt(e[1]), 0)
      var endTime = new Date(parseInt(f[2]), parseInt(f[1])-1, parseInt(f[0]), parseInt(g[0]), parseInt(g[1]), 0)
      var event = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc });
      spreadsheet.getRange(+x + 2, col).setValue(event.getId())
      if (color) {
        event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried with your code but I have this error Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

Comment: Yes they are in the right format...

Comment: I have updated my answer, add then the description

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for your reply. And so, in addition to my code, what is the final script?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it is ok. I can't teste because there is no file but it seems that it could work.

Comment: I have this error e.getHours is not a function

Comment: what is the value in shift[4] (column E) ? can you share a sample spreadsheet ? I tried myself the previous code I posted and I didn't get any error.

Comment: Is the hours https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jo8TmUyb4zmGsAS4e1DJCsdHnCJlQGRUiYdKSVVvKR4/edit#gid=0

Comment: in E and G you have text, not values ! that's the reason

Comment: Perfect, now works!

Comment: Hello Mike. There is a problem on the calendars. All the events are duplicated. Why?

Comment: To prevent duplication, you have to save the id or a flag on the rows that has been already treated. Do you have a free column and which ? il will update my answer. We can store the id in column A (what is the actual value in A?) or in column I of your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: in fact, I have added a test `if (shift[0]=='')` in the other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150892/15019380

Comment: Hello. I have in the col A the ID, and from the column M, all the columns avalables

Comment: Hello, I have inserted your new code but nothing happens. The events are not created. My sheet contains the IDs (col A) for the events already created and I have added the new empty col N as your suggest, but nothing happens...

Comment: I apologize, corrected ! you can try also in your dummy spreadsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jo8TmUyb4zmGsAS4e1DJCsdHnCJlQGRUiYdKSVVvKR4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

#### Current Date and Time

```
function currentdatetime() {
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = 60 * second;
  const hour = minute * 60;
  const day = hour * 24;
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = dt.valueOf();
  const td = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate())
  const dv = td.valueOf();
  const d = dtv - dv;
  let hours = Math.floor(d % day / hour);
  let minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
  let seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
  Logger.log(`Date: ${td.getMonth() + 1}/${td.getDate()}/${td.getFullYear()} - Time:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`)
}

Execution log
9:05:08 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:05:09 AM  Info    Date: 5/4/2022 - Time:9:5:9
9:05:09 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

#### A simpler way

```
function currentdatetime() {
  const dt = new Date();
  Logger.log(`Date: ${dt.getMonth() + 1}/${dt.getDate()}/${dt.getFullYear()} - Time:${dt.getHours()}:${dt.getMinutes()}:${dt.getSeconds()}`)
}

Execution log
9:11:19 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:11:20 AM  Info    Date: 5/4/2022 - Time:9:11:20
9:11:20 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

#### Super simple way

```
function currentdatetime() {
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"))
}

Execution log
9:16:22 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:16:23 AM  Info    05/04/2022 - 09:16:23
9:16:23 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

#### Joining date and time

```
function currentdatetime(M=5,d=4,y=2022,H=9,m=28,s=0) {
  const dt = new Date(y,M-1,d,H,m,s);
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  return dt;
}

Execution log
9:29:38 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:29:39 AM  Info    05/04/2022 09:28:00
9:29:39 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Hello Cooper. This code is to join the var startTime with shift[3] (Start Date) and shift[4] (Start time) and so, to join the var endTime with shift[5] (End Date) and shift[6] (End time)?

Comment: As long as  they are stored as milliseconds then you can always just add them back together.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. As you can see the code in the question, I refer only from 2 columns for start (shift[3]) and end date (shift[5]) and they contains only the date. The columns for start and end time are on another two columns, the question is how to join data and time for startDate and data and time for endDate. Thanks

Comment: I have tried with  var startTime = shift[3] + shift[4] and var endTime = shift[5] + shift[6] but not works

Comment: How do you store you date and how do you store you time?

Comment: In the spreadsheet in the right format, but I have 2 different columns for date and time and so in the calendar the event is created only with the date because the time is in another column, the same for end date. And so, how to join var startTime and endTime with both date and time?

Comment: are the date and time both strings.  What is there datatype?

Comment: Hello, this is the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jo8TmUyb4zmGsAS4e1DJCsdHnCJlQGRUiYdKSVVvKR4/edit?usp=sharing