# Sync Google Sheet and Google Calendar by ID preventing duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

With this code I could put the events from google spreadsheet to google calendar, but now I would to sync these events between the two platforms by a unique ID I could store in the spreadsheet.

First of all, I am trying to set a trigger every 5 minutes, but I don't know if it is the best solution, considering also that the events on the sheet are more than 300 (and they could increase, but with 5 or 6 new events every day) and so I would avoid the error *Error: "You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time."*

The second thing I am trying to do is to call the id from the google calendar to the column A of the sheet but without success.

How could I proceed?

```
function sendToCal() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('XCALENDAR')
  let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxx");
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:M").getValues();

  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];

    let d = shift[3]
    let e = shift[4].split(":")
    let f = shift[5]
    let g = shift[6].split(":")

    var startTime = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),parseInt(e[0]),parseInt(e[1]),0);
    var endTime   = new Date(f.getFullYear(),f.getMonth(),f.getDate(),parseInt(g[0]),parseInt(g[1]),0);
    var nameevent = shift[1];
    var desc = shift[11];
    var color = shift[12];
    var event = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc });

    if (color) {
      event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with limited signups (with getLastRow()) and getDisplayValues() to prevent any issue with formatting (assuming your dates are dd/MM/yyyy)

```
function sendToCal() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('XCALENDAR')
  let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxx");
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:M" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();

  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) { 
    var shift = signups[x];
    if (shift[0]==''){
    let d = shift[3].split("/")
    let e = shift[4].split(":")
    let f = shift[5].split("/")
    let g = shift[6].split(":")

    var startTime = new Date(parseInt(d[2]), parseInt(d[1])-1, parseInt(d[0]), parseInt(e[0]), parseInt(e[1]), 0)
    var endTime = new Date(parseInt(f[2]), parseInt(f[1])-1, parseInt(f[0]), parseInt(g[0]), parseInt(g[1]), 0)
    var nameevent = shift[1];
    var desc = shift[11];
    var color = shift[12];
    var event = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc });
    spreadsheet.getRange('A' + (+x + 2)).setValue(event.getId())
    if (color) {
      event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. thanks for your reply, I have the same error: d.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: impossible because i don't use getfullyear in this piece of code, pls retry!

Comment: Done! but now appears this error: shift[3].split is not a function

Comment: sorry, replace by getDisplayValues()

Comment: Works partially. It not send the last events in the sheet. I have this error Exception: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later.

Comment: of course, you have to divide your work in lighter packages. You can for instance check if column A is empty to try again some minutes later

Comment: I have added a test to do so.

Comment: Hello. All works good, but the events are created in the calendar 1 month after the real event. Why?

Comment: ok sorry, I have added -1 to the monthes

Answer (score 1):

Well,

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to have a sheet of events, each with it's own identifier, and make sure they are always in sync.

If this is correct, my advice is to just use the event ID as your identifier on the sheet and when running your script, to only target events in the sheet without an identifier.

For getting the event ID, simple as:

```
// var event = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc });
const eventID = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc }).getId();
```

You could append it where you would like, though I think first or second column would be best.

Try:

```
function sendToCal() {

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('XCALENDAR')
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxx");
  const signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:M").getValues();

  const targetEvents = signups.filter(i => i[0] === ``);

  for (let newEvent of targetEvents) {

    const rowIndex = signups.findIndex(i => i === newEvent);

    const [d, e, f, g] = [newEvent[3], newEvent[4].split(":"), newEvent[5], newEvent[6].split(":")];
    const [nameevent, desc, color] = [newEvent[1], newEvent[11], newEvent[12]];

    const startTime = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),parseInt(e[0]),parseInt(e[1]),0);
    const endTime   = new Date(f.getFullYear(),f.getMonth(),f.getDate(),parseInt(g[0]),parseInt(g[1]),0);
    
    const eventID = eventCal.createEvent(nameevent, startTime, endTime, { description: desc }).getId();

    const updatedRow = [eventID, ...newEvent];
    spreadsheet.getRange(rowIndex+2, 1, 1, updatedRow.length).setValues([updatedRow])

    if (color) {
      event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
    }

  }

}
```

The main changes are:

- Increasing the original `signups` range.
- Targeting only events without an ID (`targetEvents`).
- Increasing all indexed values by 1 due to new ID column.
- Update row after creating event to include ID.

If you have any issues please let me know!

Comment: Hello @newaza thanks for your reply, I have added the column A for the ID, but after run the script, this column (col A) remains empty and nothing happens on the calendar, so the events are not created or updated.

Comment: Move the new column to column B ;)

As a warning, because there are no IDs currently in your sheet, it will look to create events you may have already created. If need be, add some values to the empty cells of events you know have been created, or try retrieving their IDs and adding them in.

Comment: So I have the columns A and B empty, but if now I add a new event to the sheets, nothing happens to the calendar.

Comment: To clarify, you should only be adding one new column "right of" Column A as stated in my post. If Column A was already empty, let me know and I can edit the code for you. This will not work if you've added two new columns. ... As for nothing happening when you add a new event, do you have a trigger already installed? Are you running the function manually?

Comment: If you want, I can add the existing unique ID to the column A or B. The existing events have already the unique ID. Now, tell me if the new column must to be A or B. Now, I run the script manually, then I will set a trigger every 10 minutes

Comment: The code is expecting [ Original Column A, New Column B, Original Column C, ... ], if you already had Column A being used for unique IDs, please specify and I can update the code

Comment: Yes, now the situation is this [ Original Column A, New Column B, Original Column C, ... ] and the column A is used for for unique IDs

Comment: Please remove the empty Column B. [ Original Col A, Original Col B, Original Col C, ... ], the code has been updated. Please run and post any errors that follow.

Comment: I have this error TypeError: d.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: Log the newEvent array and check values, this error would generally mean newEvent[3] is not a date.

Comment: I have not done any edit to the format of the column 3 in the sheet. It is in the right format (date)...

Comment: I did not ask any of that. You should log your array to see what the values are as the 3rd index is not a date. Column 3 would be newEvent[2].

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the field numbers